# How to restrict my flex appliaction based on installed Adobe AIR version?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, installation, adobe

For a instance I want my flex application to install if and only if the system has Adobe AIR version is higher than 4.0. otherwise I should show the error while my flex application installation process. This has to checked for both windows and MAC systems. Please any one help to solve this issue.

Comment: I had tried to get AIR version using NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion. I am geting the AIR version. But I couldn't restrict my installer by checking AIR version on my preinit cycle.

Comment: Post the code that you have tired in your question so that people have an easier time helping you out.

Comment: If I remember correctly, setting the app.xml namespace to 4.0 should restrict this, assuming you are using the Adobe AIR installer and not a native installer. I did some testing back in version 3.1-3.3 (~2 years ago) and that was the case. Does this not work anymore?

Comment: BTW, I've updated my answer to take overlaying AIR on the Flex SDK into account.

Answer (score 1):

Update your project-app.xml file with the desired AIR version.

From the [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fff) on the subject:

> xmlns — the XML namespace attribute determines the required AIR
>   runtime version of the application.
>
> The namespace changes with each major release of AIR (but not with
>   minor patches). The last segment of the namespace, such as “3.0,”
>   indicates the runtime version required by the application.

Edit:  From your comments, it sounds like you have the wrong version of AIR overlaid on your Flex SDK.  Just download the AIR SDK "for Flex users" and overlay it on a fresh instance of the Flex SDK.

The download link to overlay on an existing instance of the Flex SDK is really sneaky!

[image: AIR SDK download page with stealthy download links highlighted]

Comment: I am using flash builder 4.0. In it the Flex SDK 4.1.0, but on overlaying the AIR SDK 4.0 on top it I am getting compile time error.

Comment: Ah, you've probably downloaded the AIR SDK with compiler.  That's a simple fix.